# 8 GB RAM in a Lenovo W500?

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop

I've just bought 2 x [4gb Corsair CM3X4GSD1066](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UOPXVG) memory bricks. I've now however read that people have had problems getting these to work on a W500 - but *is there* a way to do it or should I just return them ASAP? If so - what bricks *will* work? If any ...

Comment: Turks out they worked just fine for me and the w500!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had no trouble getting 16GB of RAM to work on a W510 (which is largely the same as a W500, but those only support 8GB and I don't think I've tried more than 6GB on one...), but I've never tried these particular DIMMs.  (I have never had luck with Corsair.)  I was using Kingston, personally.  Really, though, the best thing to do is buy the RAM directly from Lenovo - it may be slightly overpriced, but it will carry the warranty coverage of the laptop if you do this!

Comment: what RAM did you use to get 16GB of RAM to work on a Lenovo W500?

Comment: @antheo - Doh, this is totally a typo on my part.  The W500 only supports 8GB - I meant a W510. >.<  They're largely the same except for that which was sort of my point - ThinkPads are pretty robust.  (I edited the post - thank you.)

Comment: 16GB will not work in the w500. I just tested it with 2x8GB team ram sticks. The computer makes a pattern of beeps and then shuts off without displaying anything on the screen.

Comment: @ntw1103 - That's what it says - the 500 series doesn't support that much.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to iterate that it has been tested. :) I was once told you couldn't use an intel 6250 wifi/wimax card in a thinkpad x60t, even with an unlocked BIOS. It actually was possible after covering pin 15 on the pci-e card. I did mark your answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a 64bit OS to have all the 8GB viewed/usable that's all
You can stress test these RAM using Memtest?

Comment: Or you could use a 32-bit OS that uses PAE. Each process would still be limited to 4GB of address space though.

Comment: Yeah, I have x64 but what do I have to do to make the RAM viewed/usable?